# The data is not displayed in the output table

Tags: tabularray, csvsimple-l3

Input files have a variable number of columns. The output table is correctly formed based on the input data, but the data is not displayed in the table. There are no errors when compiling the Latex file.

The packages csvsimple-l3 and tabularray are used in the Latex code, so it is also a requirement that they be used in some new example that would eliminate the error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{file3.csv}
  a,b,c
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{file4.csv}
  a,b,c,d
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myheader}{m}{Sample & Span~over~3~or~4~columns  
\prg_replicate:nn {#1} { & } Last &}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Disorders}[1]{%
 \readdef{#1}\filedata%
 \begin{tblr}[expand=\expanded]{vlines,hlines,
 colspec={X[1,c,m]*{\ncols}{X[1,c,m]} X[1,c,m]X[1,c,m]},
 width=\textwidth,
 cell{1}{1}={r=2}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries},
 cell{1}{2}={c=\ncols}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries},
 cell{1}{\ncols+2}={c=2}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries},
}
\expanded{\myheader{\ncols}}
\\
\csvreader[no head]{#1}{}{
 \ifnumequal{\ncols}{4}{%
       &\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcoliv&Result & Erros\\
                            }{%
 \ifnumequal{\ncols}{3}{%
       &\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&Result & Erros
                           }{}%
                            }
}
\end{tblr}
}

\Disorders{file3.csv}
\bigskip

The file consists of \ncols{} columns.

\end{document}
```

What is the mistake?
If anyone knows the answer and has a solution it would be very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, I limited the packages to `tabularray` and `csvsimple-l3`.
The main difficulty was `table head`. In the documentation `section 3.11 Data Collection` we can read:

> Using computations or not expandable conditionals may likely cause
> compilation errors.

Hence the test `\ifnumequal{\thecsvrow}{1}`

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/706097/the-data-is-not-displayed-in-the-output-table
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%<-- ifnumequal
%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{file3.csv}
    a,b,c
    d,e,f
    g,h,i
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{file4.csv}
a,b,c,d
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myheader}{m}{Sample & Span~over~3~or~4~columns  
\prg_replicate:nn {#1} { & } Last &}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\csvreader[
no head,
tabularray =
{
    vlines,hlines,
    colspec={X[1,c,m] *{\thecsvcolumncount}{X[1,c,m]} X[1,c,m] X[1,c,m]},
    width=\textwidth,
    cell{1}{1}={r=2}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries},
    cell{1}{2}={c=\thecsvcolumncount}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries},
    cell{1}{\thecsvcolumncount+2}={c=2}{c,m,font=\small\bfseries},
    },
% table head = Sample & Span~over~3~or~4~columns&&&\\
]{file4.csv}{}
{   
    \ifnumequal{\thecsvrow}{1}
        {\myheader{\thecsvcolumncount}\\}
        {}
    \ifnumequal{\thecsvcolumncount}{4}
        {%
        &\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&\csvcoliv&Result & Erros
        }
        {%
            \ifnumequal{\thecsvcolumncount}{3}
                {%
                    &\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii&Result & Erros
                }
                {}%
        }
}


\bigskip
The file consists of \thecsvcolumncount{} columns.
\end{document}
```

[image]